# Can a relationship have a unique attribute? E-R Diagram E-R model

Tags: database, database-design

In an E-R Diagram, can a relationship have its own unique attribute? for example:

Entity A------[relationship]-------Entity B
For example: relationship has an attribute that is underlined(aka its own unique attribute) along with the keys of the entities in the relationship to form its own key?

for example Entity A has key A, Entity B has key B, relationship has key C and Entity A and Entity B have a many-many relationship between them, therefore is the schema = R(A,B,C) with the primary key A,B, and C?

Comment: There is no one ER method. What is your textbook name & edition? What does your textbook have to say about this & how is it unclear? In particular: True/Chen EF uses diamonds in ERDs for relationships/associations & lines are participations/FKs. While in pseudo-ERs every box is simultaneous an entity & association & lines may be "relationships" meaning FKs & may be relationships/assocations or may give cardinalities for relationships/associations that are *projections* of shown or implied ones. Eg see the ER wikipedia page to see the (partially explicitly addressed) mess of notions/notations.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, it's reasonable to have attributes associated with relationships and to have uniqueness constraints on those attributes. However, there are several varieties of ER modelling techniques, notations and conventions and between them there will be differences as to how to model that situation.

You tagged this question as database design. Not all ER models are intended to be database designs but if you are designing a database then the underlying data model of your intended database will be relevant. In a *relational* database, for example, entities and relationships are both implemented in the same way: as relations. So for a relational database you don't necessarily need to distinguish between attributes of an entity and attributes of a relationship because they will all become attributes of a relation schema (i.e. tables). This is something you could consider when deciding how to represent things in your diagram.

Comment: I appreciate everyone taking their time to answer this. If I may add to the question, this is in particular talking about an E-R diagram that would be later turned into a relational schema. Therefore, the relationship would be a tuple on its own in the form R(A,B,C,D) having its primary key consist of the primary keys of the participating entities(considering it is a many-many relationship) and as well consisting of its own unique attribute(underlined attribute in ER diagram) being added to as a part of that primary key. In this case is it possible? Or is this wrong?

Comment: A key has to be irreducibly unique which means that if an attribute is unique then it is a key in its own right - it cannot be part of another key. From your description it seems that R has two keys: {A,B,C,D} and {Z} where Z is the "own unique attribute". You can pick either one of those as the primary key.

Comment: I see, thanks. Just one more question for clarification: Can an entity set reference a relationship, meaning that in the relational schema, the entity set would be its own tuple with the primary key consisting of its key and the keys it has gotten from referencing a relationship, or is that not possible?

Comment: Possible, yes, because relationships are just attributes in a relation. A tuple is basically a "row" in a relation schema / table. Design is normally all about the schema, not the tuples.

Comment: I see. So in order for an Entity to reference a relationship, would it be a Many-to One arrow from the Entity to the relationship in an E-R Model?

Comment: Perhaps. Chen diagrams do distinguish between entities and relationships, usually by using a diamond shape for relationships. But I don't think I have ever seen a Chen diagram used for a real database design. Chen notation is more typically used in conceptual modelling and for teaching purposes. In relational database design the "relationships with attributes" get made into entities - so the questions you are asking don't apply. If you try to use a Chen diagram in the way you have described then I wonder how many people will understand your diagram.

Comment: I see. I made an image and uploaded it here https://imgur.com/a/fMY6xLE that shows more specifically what I mean. Would this be allowed in an E-R diagram following the stanford dialect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take the example having a many to many relationship between let's say invoice and items, I like to have the datetime as an attribute in the relationship, this has to be part of the primary key of the relationship. So when we model the E_R diagram we underline the attribute date or invoicedate